# htaccess redirect if domain not contain keyword

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How can I redirect if the domain not contains some keyword?

Example:

my domain with the allowed access is

```
www.example.net/example/thisisallowed*
```

or

```
www.example.net/examplefolder/thisisallowedtwo
```

And ALL other URLS like per example

```
www.example.net/example/notallowed
```

or

```
www.example.net/example/anotheruri
```

are forbidden?

So that all URLS WITHOUT my URL Key thisisallowed should be redirected to:

```
www.example.net/example/thisisallowed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.net$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/thisisallowed [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.net/example/thisisallowed [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: thx for your answer. Sadly this is not work... :-/ I get this Error:
Error: Redirection error

The site is redirecting the request in a way that they will never complete .